# Javascript: TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript

Pulling my hair out here trying to understand the infuriating nuances of Javascript.  Hopefully some JS guru can take a gander, point and go, "well, there's yer problem...".

Here's a slimmed down sample of the problem:

```
var Parent = (function () {
    var func1 = function () {
        func2(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    };

    var func2 = function (callback) {
        callback('abc');
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            func1();
            func2();
        }
    };
})();
```

Call with `Parent.init();`

This fails with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
    at check2 (<anonymous>:9:9)
    at Object.init (<anonymous>:15:13)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

What's getting me, is that if I comment out the enclosing code, like so, then it works as expected:

```
// var Parent = (function () {
    var func1 = function () {
        func2(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    };

    var func2 = function (callback) {
        callback('abc');
    };

    // return {
    //     init: function () {
    //         func1();
    //         func2();
    //     }
    // };
// })();
```

...and call with `func1();`

Result:

```
abc
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your function is written with a parameter, but when you call it you pass nothing.

Comment: To turn the question around... When you call `func2();` what do you expect `callback` to be and why?

Comment: In your `init()` function, you're calling `func2();`, without specifying the `callback` function as the required argument. In your second version (with `init` commented out), you're correctly specifying the `callback` function in `func2(function (res) { ... });`.

Comment: ```func2()``` must do some processing and return a result.  My (perhaps screwed) understanding is that ```callback``` must call the "calling" anon function in ```func1()```.  lol, I dunno, hence the question.  I just want to know why it works in the one sample, but not the other.

Comment: @Reece - mmm, ok, let me give that a try.  Sounds like sound advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version, you're calling `func2()` without specifying the `callback` function, which is a required argument. In your second example (with `init` commented out), you're correctly specifying the `callback` function in `func2(function (res) { ... });`.

Is the below snippet something you're looking for?

```js
const Parent = (function () {
  const func1 = function () {
    func2(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  const func2 = function (callback) {
    callback('abc'); // this is passing 'abc' to line 3 of this snippet
  }

  return {
    init: function () {
      func1();
      // func2(); // you don't want to call "func2" here, as "func1" calls it
      // Or you could run:
      func2(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
      // But this makes "func1" redundant
    }
  };
});

Parent().init();

// Output
abc
```

Comment: Thanks @Reece, that works and makes sense.  Much appreciated!

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your question, please mark it as the solution :-). Happy to help!

Comment: ...just waiting for the mandatory countdown to end so I can click that button!

Comment: Cheers Henry! Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass callback parameter into func2 inside init. something like this.

```
init: function () {
            func1();
            func2(function (res) {
                 console.log(res);
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

From a comment on the question:

> I just want to know why it works in the one sample, but not the other.

Because in one example you pass an argument to `func2` and in the other you don't.  Look at the working version:

```
func2(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

vs. the non-working version:

```
func2();
```

The difference is that the first one passes a function which gets invoked as `callback('abc');` whereas the second one passes nothing, so the attempt to invoke the non-existant `callback` function fails.

---

As an aside, in your non-working example you call `func2` *twice*, once with the callback and once without.  So it both "works" *and* "fails" in that case.